# Difference between switch function and React(jsx,tsx) switch operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

We are currently porting our portfolio from **Javascript** to **TypeScript** using **NextJS** as frontend framework and **Strapi** as backend.

To have dynamic content we created a *dynamiczone* field inside of the *post* model and we get it from **GraphQL**.

Our problem comes when we want to render the content based on the dynamic zone type, its model is:

```js
export interface IExperience {
  id: string;
  from: Date;
  to?: Date;
  ongoing?: boolean;
  title: string;
  institution: string;
  address?: IAddress;
  url?: string;
  description?: string;
}

export interface IPersonalInformation {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  photo: IFile;
  position: string;
  nationality?: string;
  address?: IAddress;
  telephone?: ITelephone[];
  mail: string;
  links?: ISocialLink[];
  aboutMe?: string;
}

export interface IRichText {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

export type IComponent =
  | ({
      __component: "content.rich-text";
      __typename: "ComponentContentRichText";
    } & IRichText)
  | ({
      __component: "content.experience";
      __typename: "ComponentContentExperience";
    } & IExperience)
  | ({
      __component: "content.personal-information";
      __typename: "ComponentContentPersonalInformation";
    } & IPersonalInformation)
  | ({
      __component: "fields.skill";
      __typename: "ComponentFieldsSkill";
    } & ISkill);
```

The component field will extends one interface based in its type; cool, but when we go to render it we get problems:

```js
const DynamicZone: React.FC<IDynamicZone> = ({ component, className }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const selectComponent = () => {
    switch (component.__typename) {
      case "ComponentContentRichText":
        return <Content>{component.text}</Content>;
      case "ComponentContentExperience":
        return <Experience {...component} />;
      case "ComponentContentPersonalInformation":
        return <PersonalInformation {...component} />;
      case "ComponentFieldsSkill":
        return <Skill {...component} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Typography
      variant="body1"
      component="section"
      className={clsx(classes.dynamicZone, className)}
    >
      {
        {
          "content.rich-text": <Content>{component.text}</Content>, <-- Bug 1
          "content.experience": <Experience {...component} />,
          "content.personal-information": (
            <PersonalInformation {...component} /> <-- Bug 2
          ),
          "fields.skill": <Skill {...component} />,
        }[component.__component]
      }
    </Typography>
  );
};

export default DynamicZone;
```

With, bug 1:

```sh
<html>TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'IComponent'.<br/>Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ __component: &quot;content.experience&quot;; __typename: &quot;ComponentContentExperience&quot;; } &amp; IExperience'.
```

And bug 2:

```sh
<html>TS2322: Type '{ __component: &quot;content.rich-text&quot;; __typename: &quot;ComponentContentRichText&quot;; id: string; text: string; } | { __component: &quot;content.experience&quot;; __typename: &quot;ComponentContentExperience&quot;; ... 8 more ...; description?: string | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes &amp; IPersonalInformation &amp; { children?: ReactNode; }'.<br/>Type '{ __component: &quot;content.rich-text&quot;; __typename: &quot;ComponentContentRichText&quot;; id: string; text: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IPersonalInformation': name, photo, position, mail
```

Why is it assing the type improperly?

Ok, if we change it to `selectComponent` function, it does not give any error:

```js
const DynamicZone: React.FC<IDynamicZone> = ({ component, className }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const selectComponent = () => {
    switch (component.__typename) {
      case "ComponentContentRichText":
        return <Content>{component.text}</Content>;
      case "ComponentContentExperience":
        return <Experience {...component} />;
      case "ComponentContentPersonalInformation":
        return <PersonalInformation {...component} />;
      case "ComponentFieldsSkill":
        return <Skill {...component} />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Typography
      variant="body1"
      component="section"
      className={clsx(classes.dynamicZone, className)}
    >
      {selectComponent()}
    </Typography>
  );
};
```

Esentially, it is the same thing, so, why it does not give typing errors with `switch case` but it does with `{{}[]}`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided a type guard in `selectComponent()` by switching between the values of `component.__typename`, which narrows the type that `component` can be. Since the case of `"ComponentContentRichText"` can only narrow down to a single type in the `IComponent` union,
`{ __component: "content.rich-text"; __typename: "ComponentContentRichText"; } & IRichText`,
it is known that the `text` property exists on `component` via the `IRichText` interface.

In the example of dynamic selection with an object and index (`{...}[...]`), you have not narrowed the type of `component`. The object is created with all of the members - regardless of the `component.__component` value - and then the value is selected dynamically with an index of the `component.__component` value. The transpiler cannot tell that `text` is a valid property of `component` at the time that the object is created.

You could add type guards in the dynamic selection's object instantiation using [conditional statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). However, this method is not optimal because there are additional run-time checks to be made.

```
<Typography>
  {
    {
      'content.rich-text': component.__component === 'content.rich-text'
        ? <Content>{ component.text }</Content>
        : undefined,
      /* ... */
    }[component.__component]
  }
</Typography>
```

Or, you could use chained conditional statements to select the result.

```
<Typography>
  {
    component.__component === 'content.rich-text'
      ? <Content>{ component.text }</Content>
      : component.__component === 'content.experience'
        ? <Experience { ...component } />
        : /* ... */
  }
</Typography>
```

An alternative to the `selectComponent()` anonymous function to keep the definition inline with the JSX, would be to define an anonymous function and call it immediately. Using a function - whether named, anonymous and defined earlier, or anonymous and called immediately - has the added benefits of being cleaner, easier to reason about, and being able to use `switch` statement optimizations such as jump tables.

```
<Typography>
  {
    function() {
      switch (component.__component) {
        case 'content.rich-text':
          return <Content>{ component.text }</Content>
        /* ... */
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }()
  }
</Typography>
```

Comment: Is there any way to provide a type guard in dynamic selection? Which is the best way?

Comment: @SalahAdDin I recommend using the `selectComponent()` method because it is much cleaner. You could also use a [conditional statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) as a type guard, but switch statements generally have some optimizations by being transformed into a jump table. If you want to keep it all inline, you could define an anonymous function and call it immediately in the JSX block: `<MyContainer>{ function() { /* ... */ }() }</MyContainer>`

Comment: You can add type guards in the dynamic selection method by checking the value of `component.__component` when setting the object properties, for example `{ 'content.rich-text': component.__component === 'content.rich-text' ? component.text : undefined }[component.__component]`, but this adds another layer of complexity to instantiating the object. Better to use a simple function that is easy to read and reason about.

Comment: Can you add this comment to the answer? Then, i will accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SalahAdDin I've added alternatives to the answer.